# Group values based on 2 columns

Tags: r, data.table

This is probably a very easy question, however I tried searching for it but I haven't found a solution.

I have an extensive dataset consisting of 65 columns and 3.5mln rows. 
This date is as following:

```
GR SR var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var6

1 2   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   x    


1  2   x    x    x   ""    ""  ""   

1  2   ""   ""   ""  ""   ""   ""   

1  3   x    x   x   x  "" "" 

1  3   "" ""  "" "" "" ""
```

Where `"" = NULL`

I want to update the var 1 to 6 based on the other variables. So for each GR and SR if var1 to var6 contains an x it needs to be updated with an x. This would lead to the following table:

```
GR SR var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6

1 2 x x x "" "" x 

1 2 x x x "" "" x 

1 2 x x x "" "" x    

1 3 x x x x "" "" 

1 3 x x x x "" ""
```

After I have found these records I want to remove the duplicate records, but I know how to do this with `Unique` form `library(data.table)`

Does anybody knows how to do this?

Comment: Share data with `dput(head(data))`....

Comment: "`"" = NUll`" this part is confusing. You mean `NA`?, or it's literally `""` (string with `nchar() == 0`)

Comment: I mean with "" that these are empty

Comment: Is that `nchar(x) == 0` or `is.na(x)`?

Comment: In R, `""` is still a string, `NA` is a missing value, and `NULL` is a null object. An existing column is unlikely to own `NULL` in it (unless it's a list). Please specify what the `""` mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution use `fill()` in `tidyr` (load `tidyverse` first):

```
df %>% group_by(GR, SR) %>%
  fill(starts_with("var")) %>%
  fill(starts_with("var"), .direction = "up")

#      GR    SR var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6 
#   <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1     1     2 x     x     x     NA    NA    x    
# 2     1     2 x     x     x     NA    NA    x    
# 3     1     2 x     x     x     NA    NA    x    
# 4     1     3 x     x     x     x     NA    NA   
# 5     1     3 x     x     x     x     NA    NA
```

I presume the empty elements are `NA`. If they are strings `""`, then you need to transform them to `NA` or the code above won't work.

```
# How to recode all "" to NA?
# Insert the following code between group_by() and fill()
mutate_all(funs(na_if(., ""))) %>%
```

---

```
# data
df <- structure(list(GR = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
SR = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), var1 = c(NA, "x", NA, "x", NA),
var2 = c(NA, "x", NA, "x", NA), var3 = c(NA, "x", NA, "x", NA),
var4 = c(NA, NA, NA, "x", NA), var5 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_,
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), var6 = c("x", NA, NA, NA, NA)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: please `library(tidyverse)` and try again

Answer (score 1):

Very easily done in `data.table` syntax:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(my_data)
cols = paste0('var', 1:6)
my_data[ , by = .(GR, SR), 
        (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) if (any(x == 'x')) 'x' else '')]
```

If I'm not mistaken, you can simply remove the `(cols) :=` part to accomplish both steps (i.e., also getting `unique`) at once:

```
my_data[ , by = .(GR, SR), 
        lapply(.SD, function(x) if (any(x == 'x')) 'x' else '')]
```

Comment: I get what you're trying to do but I get a "Error in if (any(X == "X")) "X" else "" : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Comment: @Qris that is, indeed your `""` are not `""` but `NA_character_`. Try with `na.rm = TRUE` in `any`